# CRM 2013: Confirmation box on business process flow using Javascript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, business-process

I think its a little problem for you gurus, I want to add a confirmation box on stage completion of Business process flow. So I want to seek your kind help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not (yet) familiar with business process flows, but I understand they're basically real-time workflows attached to the form: I'd attempt "cheating" the system like this:

1. Add two new fields to the form, make them hidden and readonly
2. Attach to one of the new field's onchange the code to request confirmation
3. Split the flow in two parts, *before* and *after* the confirmation
4. The first half is what you invoke in place of what you have now
5. Attach to the other field the second half of the flow
6. The onchange will request confirmation
7. on confirm, change the second field's value (so the second half of the flow runs)

Logic similar to when you needed to perform real-time processsing through plugins (change hidden field - save - preupdate plugin)